# salesforce1 javascript navigation library navigateToURL

Tags: salesforce1-app

I like to add custom "new" page in saleforce1 and this can be easily achieved by overriding "new" action on a particular object.( "new" button displayed on top of list view ) However when saving the content and transition to list view page it's possible to go back to "new" page. Since this is the object in the related page I need to use navigateToRelatedList so it doesn't give the option to navigate away without retaining navigation history(navigateToURL gives option to do that, but I can't use it because I don't know the absolute path to related list page).

How this can be solved so that after saving the content on the object and transition to the list view it doesn't go back to the createn new page.